# Hide Input / Outputs in Compiled FMUs

Tags: modelica, dymola, fmi

I would like to export an FMU with a controlled selection of inputs and outputs.

I have a model which compiles to an FMU successfully but several internal variables are appearing as output variables in the FMU.

Is there an option to hide these variables while compiling the FMU?

For example, I would expect my model to have 3 inputs and 6 outputs. However, after compiling, the FMU has 26 variables from internal models. These variables receive updates that will change internally to the model as time progresses.

I am using Dymola 2019 (though I could use any version).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Did you try to set the options in the Model description filter? Activating the "Black box" checkbox should hide pretty much everything except in-/outputs. For your question the "Auxiliary variables" option could be a good fit. By default only "Protected variables" are activated, which of course offers another option as well: Protecting the variables you don't want to be visible in the FMU in your model.

[image]